# Estimote beacons proximity demo pushing a ViewController on "Immediate" Case

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, estimote

i m working on estimote beacon.

I try to present a ViewController when i m in switch Case "immediate".
But when i the view is loaded, i have a warning :

2014-03-13 02:44:26.017 ProximityDemo[856:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Why ? I think the presentView Method is still working while i m on the new view.

Also when i m on the new View , i would like to pop to old view when i m in Case "Near"

I Think i have to implement all the the code in the new ViewController ?                      (presentProductViewController)
Is there a way to have all the proximity/distance controll in only one Controller ?

Here is my code :

ESTViewController :

```
#import "ESTViewController.h"
#import <ESTBeaconManager.h>
#import "PresentProductViewController.h"

@interface ESTViewController () <ESTBeaconManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTBeaconManager* beaconManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTBeacon* selectedBeacon;

@end

@implementation ESTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// setup Estimote beacon manager

// craete manager instance
self.beaconManager = [[ESTBeaconManager alloc] init];
self.beaconManager.delegate = self;
self.beaconManager.avoidUnknownStateBeacons = YES;

// create sample region object (you can additionaly pass major / minor values)
ESTBeaconRegion* region = [[ESTBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:ESTIMOTE_IOSBEACON_PROXIMITY_UUID
                                                              identifier:@"EstimoteSampleRegion"];

// start looking for estimote beacons in region
// when beacon ranged beaconManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion: invoked
[self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];



}

-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
 didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
        inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
{
if([beacons count] > 0)
{

    if(!self.selectedBeacon)
    {
        // initialy pick closest beacon
        self.selectedBeacon = [beacons objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        for (ESTBeacon* cBeacon in beacons)
        {
            // update beacon it same as selected initially
            if([self.selectedBeacon.major unsignedShortValue] == [cBeacon.major unsignedShortValue] &&
               [self.selectedBeacon.minor unsignedShortValue] == [cBeacon.minor unsignedShortValue])
            {
                self.selectedBeacon = cBeacon;
            }
        }
    }



    // beacon array is sorted based on distance
    // closest beacon is the first one

    NSString* labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"Major: %i, Minor: %i\nRegion: ",
                           [self.selectedBeacon.major unsignedShortValue],
                           [self.selectedBeacon.minor unsignedShortValue]];

    // calculate and set new y position
    switch (self.selectedBeacon.proximity)
    {
        case CLProximityUnknown:
        {
            labelText = [labelText stringByAppendingString: @"Unknown"];
            break;
        }
        case CLProximityImmediate:
        {
            labelText = [labelText stringByAppendingString: @"Immediate"];

            PresentProductViewController *showViewController = [[PresentProductViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PresentProductViewController" bundle:nil];

            [self presentViewController:showViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

            break;
        }
        case CLProximityNear:
        {
            labelText = [labelText stringByAppendingString: @"Near"];
            break;

            //[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            //ESTViewController *initViewController = [[ESTViewController alloc]init];
            //[self presentViewController:initViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        case CLProximityFar:
        {
            labelText = [labelText stringByAppendingString: @"Far"];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    self.distanceLabel.text = labelText;
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

PresentProductViewController :

```
#import "PresentProductViewController.h"
#import <ESTBeaconManager.h>
#import "ESTViewController.h"

@interface PresentProductViewController () <ESTBeaconManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTBeaconManager* beaconManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTBeacon* selectedBeacon;

@end

@implementation PresentProductViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// setup Estimote beacon manager

// craete manager instance
self.beaconManager = [[ESTBeaconManager alloc] init];
self.beaconManager.delegate = self;
self.beaconManager.avoidUnknownStateBeacons = YES;

// create sample region object (you can additionaly pass major / minor values)
ESTBeaconRegion* region = [[ESTBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:ESTIMOTE_IOSBEACON_PROXIMITY_UUID
                                                              identifier:@"EstimoteSampleRegion"];

// start looking for estimote beacons in region
// when beacon ranged beaconManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion: invoked
[self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];


}

-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
 didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
        inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
{
if([beacons count] > 0)
{

    if(!self.selectedBeacon)
    {
        // initialy pick closest beacon
        self.selectedBeacon = [beacons objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        for (ESTBeacon* cBeacon in beacons)
        {
            // update beacon it same as selected initially
            if([self.selectedBeacon.major unsignedShortValue] == [cBeacon.major unsignedShortValue] &&
               [self.selectedBeacon.minor unsignedShortValue] == [cBeacon.minor unsignedShortValue])
            {
                self.selectedBeacon = cBeacon;
            }
        }
    }



    // beacon array is sorted based on distance
    // closest beacon is the first one

    self.labelText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"Major: %i, Minor: %i\nRegion: ",
                           [self.selectedBeacon.major unsignedShortValue],
                           [self.selectedBeacon.minor unsignedShortValue]];

    // calculate and set new y position
    switch (self.selectedBeacon.proximity)
    {
        case CLProximityUnknown:
        {
            self.labelText.text = [self.labelText.text stringByAppendingString: @"Unknown"];
            break;
        }
        case CLProximityImmediate:
        {
            self.labelText.text = [self.labelText.text stringByAppendingString: @"Immediate"];
            break;
        }
        case CLProximityNear:
        {
            self.labelText.text = [self.labelText.text stringByAppendingString: @"Near"];
            break;

            //UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil];
            //UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];

            //[self.navigationController pushViewController:initViewController animated:YES];

            //ESTViewController *initViewController = [[ESTViewController alloc]init];
            //[self presentViewController:initViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

            //[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        }
        case CLProximityFar:
        {
            self.labelText.text = [self.labelText.text stringByAppendingString: @"Far"];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

}
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I m sure i m doing wrong.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ESTBeaconManager` is probably continuously delivering the latest changes via `didRangeBeacons:inRegion` even when you have presented `PresentProductViewController`. I think the following is what happens:

1. `ESTViewController`'s `didRangeBeacons:inRegion` is called with a non-empty array of beacons.
2. The `proximity` property of the selected beacons is `CLProximityImmediate`, and `PresentProductViewController` is presented modally.
3. While being the presenting (*not* presented), viewcontroller, `ESTViewController`'s `didRangeBeacons:inRegion` is called with new changes. Again, a beacon has proximity immediate, and a new instance of `PresentProductViewController` is presented modally.

From [ViewController Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

> Any view controller object can present a single view controller at a time.

If the assumption outlined above is correct, you are trying to present multiple viewcontrollers modally at the same time, which is not a valid action. You could try to stop ranging for beacons when the view disappears, and then start ranging again when it appears. This will prevent the beacon manager from notifying `ESTViewController` of changes while it is not in a position to present viewcontrollers. Override `viewWillDisappear` and `viewWillAppear` methods to achieve this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.beaconManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.beaconManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Muncken. It worked for the warning message. Can you help me for the pop back please ? When i m in immediate case , i present the new view without getting warning message. Now i want the view pop back when i go away from the beacon.

Comment: Its ok, i found it. I used Storyboard. and i simply added [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in the swith case "near" in presentViewController. Thx again

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out.